# Check the performance of the application?

Tags: android, performance, power-management

Hey, I finished my code and everything works as it should but I'm wondering since smartphones have limited battery, CPU .. How can I check if my application will run good on older phones? and how can I check if my app consumes the phones battery?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The only way to really know it to test the app in the phones.**

That said, you can profile it and make educated guesses based on how CPU-intensive is your app, for how long is it running, if you have services using cpu continuously, etc.

There are a few things to consider:

- The main battery drain is the screen. If you keep any kind of screen lock (even dim), it will destroy the battery.
- Any other lock (wifi, etc.), will induce battery drain. Do you use them? Do you need them? Do you release them as soon as they're not needed?
- Do you have hardware listeners (e.g., location, accelerometer), unregister them as soon as they're not needed

Take a look at this video: http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/CodingLifeBatteryLife.html

Comment: Awesome video tutorial and way you explain

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look on 
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html